macOS symbolic link (ln -s) creates invalid link for a specific file
I am on macOS Sonoma 14.6.1 and have three JavaScript source files in a source folder and am using ln -s to create symbolic links to them in two target folders.
For one of these files each of its two links points to itself and not to the source file. I have tried various means of duplicating the source file, including rewriting it from an editor, to no avail. The links of the other two source files are okay.
The only difference that I can see between the problem file and the other two is that each of the other two has one or two extended attributes and the problem file has none. One of the other two has com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms and both have com.apple.lastuseddate#PS. I don't know whether this difference from the problem file is significant.
I can work around this issue by duplicating the source file into the target directories, but of course linking is more desirable.
Command:
$ ~/dev/keyboards/Custom/Ergogen
cd brec36/brec36-footprints #source directory

$ ~/dev/keyboards/Custom/Ergogen/brec36/brec36-footprints
ln -s elite-c.js ../brec36L/footprints/elite_c.js

# ls alias to show result:
$ ~/dev/keyboards/Custom/Ergogen/brec36/brec36-footprints
ll ../brec36L/footprints/elite_c.js
lrwxr-xr-x 1 brec wheel 10 Aug 21 09:52 ../brec36L/footprints/elite_c.js@ -> elite-c.js


Can you demonstrate the exact commands you've used?

@grawity_u1686 added to OP

You used:
ln -s elite-c.js ../brec36L/footprints/elite_c.js

ln -s actually does not interpret the "target" parameter as being relative to the current directory. Instead, it just stores the specified path as the symlink target without any modification (and without even checking whether the target exists) – if you specified elite-c.js, then the text elite-c.js will be stored as the link target, without any note of your current directory.
Once stored as the link target, the text now gets interpreted as relative to the location of the link, i.e. in this example it becomes relative to ../brec36L/footprints/.
To avoid this, you need either to preemptively convert the path to one that'd be relative to the link location (Linux has realpath for this, I don't know whether macOS has anything similar), or cd into the link location so that the shell's tab-completion would help you with that. For example:
ln -s "../brec36/footprints/elite_c.js" ../brec36L/footprints/

or
cd ../brec36L/footprints
ln -s ../brec36/footprints/elite_c.js

Linux (GNU Coreutils) nowadays has the -r option that makes the command behave more sensibly – ln -s -r does convert the target to an appropriately relative path – but I don't think macOS does.

Thanks! I'm so sure this answer is correct that I'm marking it as accepted before a verification trial.

I have re-created the OP's directory structure and I think the right command is ln -s ../../brec36-footprints/elite-c.js ../brec36L/footprints/elite_c.js.
